# Get random images in PHP from another website directory

Tags: php

I've got a load of images which I'd like to be randomly selected, but under the free hosting there isn't enough space to store them, so I made a second website to hold the images.

I've tried the glob command, which works on images in the same website, but doesn't seem to do anything from other websites. Directory listing is allowed, and by typing in the url I can see all of the files, but it returns nothing if I run the code. Does anyone know a way to get it working?

The code is here, the echo part is temporary

```
$images = glob('http://(mywebsite).com/images/*');
$randomImage = $images[rand(0, count($images) - 1)];
echo count($images);
```

Comment: Also, I understand I would be able to build a list of the filenames and read from that, but I don't want to have to change it each time I upload anything new

Comment: Ye you can't read a file system cross-server like that - you'd need to authenticate with the other server first but given that you are on "free" hosting I doubt this option will be open to you.  I suppose you could write a script on the images server that prints a list of images in the that directory for you to read - that way you don't have to maintain the list manually.

Comment: It also makes little sense to have PHP handle this - you'd be better writing a javascript solution.

Comment: do you know the structure of the remote urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code belongs to the remote (image) server side. I suggest you write a `rndimg.php` of sorts over there, and insert this code, referencing the resp. filesystem of course.

Then, by doing `file_get_contents('http://imgserver/rndimg.php');` or something like that, you could retreive a random image every time.

An example `rndimg.php` would be something like:

```
$images = glob('*.png');
$randomImage = $images[rand(0, count($images) - 1)];
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($randomImage));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($randomImage));
readfile($randomImage);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks man, didn't know about file_get_contents before so that was really helpful, got it all working now :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you really understand the http protocol... You cannot "dir" a remote directory over HTTP: What you get is always an HTML response. So what you can do is to fetch the Dir listing from remote:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://(mywebsite).com/images');
```

then parse the HTML code in $page for files, e.g.

```
$matches = array();
$count = preg_match_all('/\<a href=\"([^\"]+)\"\>/',$page,$m);
foreach($matches[1] as $file) {
    $img = file_get_contents('http://(mywebsite).com/images/'.$file);
}
```

and process the images.